# waitUntilObjectExists() Amazon S3 PHP SDK method, exactly how does it work?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, sdk

Will the function pause the php script until it finds the object on s3 servers?

I have it inside a foreach loop, uploading images one by one. After the object is found I call a method to delete the image locally then delete the local folder if empty. Is this a proper way of going about it? Thanks

```
foreach ($fileNames as $fileName)
{

    $imgSize = getimagesize($folderPath . $fileName);

    $width = (string)$imgSize[0];
    $height = (string)$imgSize[1];

    //upload the images
    $result = $S3->putObject(array(
        'ACL'        => 'public-read',
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => $keyPrefix . $fileName,
        'SourceFile' => $folderPath . $fileName,
        'Metadata'   => array(
            'w' => $width,
            'h' => $height
        )
    ));

    $S3->waitUntilObjectExists(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $keyPrefix . $fileName));

    $this->deleteStoreDirectory($folderPath, $fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`waitUntilObjectExists` is basically a **waiter** that periodically checks (polls) S3 at specific time intervals to see if the resource is available. The script's execution is blocked until the resource is located or the maximum number of retries is reached.

As the AWS docs defines them:

> Waiters help make it easier to work with eventually consistent systems by providing an easy way to wait until a resource enters into a particular state by polling the resource.

By default, the `waitUntilObjectExists` waiter is configured to try to locate the resource 20 times, with a 5 seconds delay between each try. You can override these default values with your desired ones by passing additional parameters to the `waitUntilObjectExists` method.

If the waiter is unable to locate the resource after the maximum number of tries, it will throw an exception.

You can learn more about waiters at:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/feature-waiters.html

For your use case, I don't think it makes sense to call `waitUntilObjectExists` after you uploaded the object, unless the same PHP script tries to retrieve the same object from S3 later in the code.

If the `putObject` API call has returned a successful response, then the object will eventually show up in S3 and you don't necessarily need to wait for this to happen before you remove the local files.

Comment: Correct, you don't need the waiter unless you need to immediately access the object.

Comment: In my case, I do need to access the object right after I transferred it to an S3 bucket. The problem in this situation is that some of the time, the object will exist in the bucket when it is requested, but because it will not have finished transferring, I end up with either incomplete images at the very first getObject call, or none at all.