# S3 waitUntilObjectExists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web app that uses S3 for storage. Sometimes one of my projects stored in S3 may be missing a resource (usually an image file) in this case I want to copy a missing image placeholder and display this instead. I am currently using copyObject but when I get the return from copyObject, the image is not yet there. I would rather not have to use a setTimeout to delay in hopes of the object actually being there a bit later so how can I do this in Javascript?

In
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049717/waituntilobjectexists-amazon-s3-php-sdk-method-exactly-how-does-it-work) there is a reference to an S3 function called waitUntilObjectExists but it seems that is a PHP only function. What would be a Javascript friendly way to do this with the Javascript sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the error event to substitute broken images:

```
function imageMissingError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/path/to/the/image/replacement.gif";
    return true;
}

<img src="thegoodimage.gif" onerror="imageMissingError(this);"/>
```